# Failure compiling the shaders, do I need openGL drivers for ubuntu on Intel platforms?

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, glsl, shader, intel

I am trying to write a simple program with vertex shaders on ubuntu, it goes like this.

```
const GLchar* vertexSource = (const GLchar*) "#version 130 core \n in vec2 position; \n void main() \n { \n gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0); \n }";
```

this is my shader, and I am compiling it like this, in the program

```
GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);  
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource,  0);  
glCompileShader(vertexShader);
```

I tried passing the length of the vertex shader string in the glShaderSourceFunction, but that is giving me the same error.

but glGetShaderiv() gives me error in compiling the code. I could not understand whats going wrong here.

Am I missing something? or its the error being raised because of the absend of the driver?

I installed ubuntu 12.04 on my Intel i5 windows 8 system, does that mean that I do not have openGL graphics drivers on ubuntu? 
could somebody please point me to where I can get them? 
besides, when the drivers are not present, isnt openGL supposed to do the whole thing in software??

Comment: What is the output of the shader's infolog?

Comment: here it is...
0:1(15): preprocessor error: syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting NEWLINE

Comment: If you had no OpenGL drivers, then you would be crashing when trying to call `glCreateShader (...)`. That is an OpenGL 2.0 function, and no platform other than OS X ships with a software fallback implementation of OpenGL 2.0+ out of the box; you can get it on Linux through Mesa, but you have to set the package up on most distros. When no hardware drivers are present on a platform like Microsoft Windows, it falls back to a software implementation of OpenGL 1.1. OS X is actually more of the exception than the rule.

Answer (score 2):

```
#version 130 core
             ^^^^ wat
```

There are no Core contexts in OpenGL 3.0.

Comment: Woah!! so that was the problem! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get your shader compilation log with following code:

```
GLint log_len;
glGetShaderiv(vertexshader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_len);
GLchar* comp_log = new GLchar[log_len + 1];
glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexshader, log_len, NULL, comp_log);
std::cout << "Shader compilation result: " << comp_log << std::endl;
delete[] comp_log;
```